# Recursive formula for n-th prime derived from a previous question

Tags: prime-numbers, recurrences

Based on my previous answer and your help

[Is there a procedure for extracting first integer $q_0$ from $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{q_k^z}$, all $0<q_0<q_1<...$ integers, $z$ complex?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300543/113386)

This formula derived in the question

$$ \ln(p_n)=-\lim\limits_{\operatorname{Re}(s) \to +\infty} \frac{\ln\left (\zeta(s)\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-s})-1 \right )}{s} $$

can actually turn into

$$ p_n=\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \left ( \frac{|B_{2m}|(2\pi)^{2m}}{2(2m)!}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-1 \right )^{-\frac1{2m}} $$

using

$$\zeta(2m) = \frac{(-1)^{m+1}B_{2m}(2\pi)^{2m}}{2(2m)!}$$

Do you see any problem in using real limit instead of complex one? (I don't.)

This recurrent formula is not known to me and if correct, it looks like something worth some attention.

The formula is more to the point in logarithm form of course:

$$ \ln(p_n)=-\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \frac1{2m}\ln \left ( \frac{|B_{2m}|(2\pi)^{2m}}{2(2m)!}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-1 \right ) $$

with a form that more clearly displays the precision it needs

$$ \ln(p_n)=-2\pi-\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \frac1{2m} \ln \left ( \frac{|B_{2m}|}{2(2m)!}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2m}} \right ) $$

which gives if we conveniently replace the internal expressions with $a_{2m}$ and $b_{2m}$:

$$ \ln(p_n)=-2\pi-\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \frac1{2m} \ln \left ( a_{2m}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-b_{2m} \right ) $$

Comment: Your first formula is not true, take for example a sequence $ s_n=\rho_n$ the sequence of non trivial zeros of zeta, then you get  $\log(-1)/\rho_n\to -\log p_n$? But if you put $\lim_{s\to+\infty}$ instead, the equation appear to be true.

Comment: I think the first limit should be as $\mathrm{Re}(s)\to\infty$, not $|s|\to\infty$.

Comment: @juan but that is saying even more that the sequence is true. If you notice the way it is derived it must be Re(s)>1. I will add that, although it is implied.

Comment: @Wojowu That is actually meant, just notation is not well chosen, because if you look at how it is derived in the previously asked questions it compares the complex values. But then that makes the entire thing still correct.

Comment: It seems like this question is related to the formula at https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3940.

Comment: @StevenClark It just confirms the initial equation from the previous question. And that is ok. I think that it just proves the point. This https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.02640.pdf even calculates using s=100, so all clear. The formula is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on

1. [Keller - A recursion equation for prime
   numbers](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3940)
2. [Kawalec - The recurrence
   formulas for primes and non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta
   function](http://arxiv.org/abs/2009.02640)

it is obvious that they meant to use or even used real values. The novelty here is that the expression has a form that you can split in two parts, one depending on $m \gg 1$ and another on $n$ where it all becomes very illustrative as some a sort of an internal sieving machine.

I would still opt of logarithm because root looks quite clumsy to deal with:

$$ \ln(p_n)=-2\pi-\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \frac1{2m} \ln \left ( a_{2m}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-b_{2m} \right ) $$

Additionally, the other summable version one of the authors is mentioning you get directly:

$$\ln(p_n)=-\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty} \frac1{2m}\ln \left ( \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p_k^{-2m})-\frac{2(2m)!}{|B_{2m}|(2\pi)^{2m}} \right )$$

which is cute.